# Visual Studio display the 'options context menu' in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Does anyone know how to open the Options context menu with keyboard shortcut?

[image]

Oh nevermind: SHIFT-ALT-F10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period).